# Psyshell for php 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

I've been using psysh on php 5.6. However, until recently I'm seeing an error that it requires php 7 or greater.

Is there a version of psysh that will work for php versions below 7?

```
 ~$ psysh

Box Requirements Checker
========================

> Using PHP 5.6.37-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
  E.


 [ERROR] Your system is not ready to run the application.                       


Fix the following mandatory requirements:
=========================================

 * The application requires the version ">=7.0.0" or greater.
```

Comment: [Additional releases—including compatibility releases for PHP 5.4, and for PHP without readline or iconv or mbstring.](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Installation)—[are available on GitHub](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/releases)

Comment: Ah thank you. I saw this earlier. There is a note about support for php 5.4 being dropped in psysh v0.9.0 but I couldn't see anything about support for versions above 5.4 being dropped

Comment: Support for PHP 5.6 ends in a few months anyway so might as well just migrate to PHP 7+.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for answering.